# How to return a pattern of numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'd like to create a method that returns the following pattern up to `n` number of rows. For example, if `n` is `5`:

pattern(n)

```
1  
22  
333  
4444  
55555
```

Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to do something? Show yor code. SO is for problem solving not for doing home work.

Comment: ah sorry, so far I have got to :

n.downto(1) do |i|
num = n.to_s
num * n

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..n).each{|i| puts (i.to_s * i) + "  "}
```

Output:

```
1  
22  
333  
4444  
55555
```

Comment: Note that the `"  "` may be a bit ironical.